# rustc: argument must be a string literal

Tags: string, rust, constants

I have test.rs:

```
const TEST: &'static str = "Test.bin";

fn main() {
    let x = include_bytes!(TEST);
}
```

> rustc test.rs

How to fix this error?

```
error: argument must be a string literal

 --> test.rs:4:22
  |
4 |     let x = include_bytes!(TEST);
  |                      ^^^^
```

Comment: How to fix ? The answer is in the question: put a string literal between the parenthesis. `let x = include_bytes!("test.bin");`

Comment: I need to take this value out of the function to make interaction with the code easier

Comment: Then you can't use this macro. Do you really expect to include in the binary something dynamic ?

Comment: Wait let me get this right, this macro can't even accept a STATIC string parameter? What kind of useless bs is this then? I mean, it is very bad practice to hardcode filenames inside functions, so who thought this would be a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro expects a string literal, so it cannot be a variable:

```rust
include_bytes!("Test.bin");
```

Alternatively you could create a macro that will expand into the desired value too:

```rust
macro_rules! test_bin {
    // `()` indicates that the macro takes no argument.
    () => {
        "Test.bin"
    };
}

fn main() {
    let x = include_bytes!(test_bin!());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=993fe67286900ad2c77ebbeaf278a0a0)